# ConcurrentHashMap thread-safety without using putIfAbsent

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I'am trying to clarify HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap regarding type-safety and also performance. I came across a lot of good articles, but still getting troubles figuring it all out.

Let's take the following example using a ConcurrentHashMap, where I will try to add a value for a key not already there and returning it, the new way of doing it would be:

```
    private final Map<K,V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return map.putIfAbsent(k, new Object());
```

let's assume we don't want to use the putIfAbsent method, the above code should look something like this:

```
    private final Map<K,V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    synchronized (map) {
        V value = map.get(key); //Edit adding the value fetch inside synchronized block 
        if (!nonNull(value)) {
            map.put(key, new Object());
        }
    }
    return map.get(key)
```

Is the problem with this approach the fact that the whole map is locked whereas in first approach the putIfAbsent method only synchronizes on the bucket on which the hash of the key is, and thus leading to less performance ? Would the second approach work fine with just a HashMap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the problem with this approach the fact that the whole map is locked

There are two problems with this approach.

### It's not intrinsic

The fact that you've acquired the lock on the `map` reference has zero effect whatsoever, except in regards to any other code that (tries) to acquire this lock. Crucially, `ConcurrentHashmap` itself **does not** acquire this lock.

So, if, during that second snippet (with synchronized), some other thread does this:

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new Object());
```

Then it may occur that your `map.get(key)` call returns null, and nevertheless your followup `map.put` call ends up overwriting. In other words, that both your thread, and that hypothetical thread running putIfAbsent, both decided to write.

Presumably, if that is just fine in your book, that'd be weird. Why use `putIfAbsent` and `check if map.get returns null` in the first place?

Had the other thread done this:

```
synchronized (map) {
  map.putIfAbsent(key, new Object());
}
```

then there'd be no problem; either your get-check-if-null-then-set code will set and the putIfAbsent call is a noop, or vice versa, but they couldn't possibly both 'decide to write'.

Which leads us to;

### This is pointless

There are two different ways to achieve concurrency with maps: Intrinsic and extrinsic. There is zero point in doing both, and they do not interact.

If you have structure whereby *all* access (both read and write) out of a plain old entirely non-multicore capable `java.util.HashMap` goes through some shared lock (the hashmap instance itself, or any other lock, long as all threads that interact with that particular map instance use the same one), then **that works fine** and there is therefore no reason or point to using `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

The **point** of ConcurrentHashMap is to streamline concurrent processes **without** the use of extrinsic locking: To let the map do the locking.

One of the reasons you want this is that the ConcurrentHashMap impl is *significantly* faster at the jobs it is capable of doing; these jobs are spelled out explicitly: It's the methods that ConcurrentHashMap has.

### Atomicity

The central problem of your code snippet is that it lacks atomicity. Check-then-act is fundamentally broken in concurrent models (in your case: **Check**: Is key 'k' associated with no value or null?, then **Act**: Set the mapping of key 'k' to value 'v'). This is broken because what if the thing you checked changes in between? What if you have two threads that both 'check-and-act' and then run simultaneously; then they both check first, then both act first, **and broken things ensue**: One of the two threads will be acting upon a state that isn't equal to the state as it was when you checked, which means your check's broken.

The right model is act-then-check: Act first, and then check the result of the operation. Of course, this requires redefining, and integrating, the code you wrote explicitly in your snippet, into the very definition of your 'act' phase.

In other words, `putIfAbsent` is **not a convenience method!** is a fundamental operation! It's the only way (short of extrinsic locking) to convey the notion of: "Perform the action of associating 'v' with 'k', but only if there is no association yet. I'll check the results of this operation next". There is no way to break that down into `if (!map.containsKey(key)) map.put(key, v);` because check-then-act does not work in concurrent modelling.

### Conclusions

Either get rid of concurrenthashmap, or get rid of synchronized. Having code that uses both is probably broken and even if it isn't, it's error prone, confusing, and I can guarantee you there's a much better way to write it (better in that it is more idiomatic, easier to read, more flexible in the face of future change requests, easier to test, and less likely to have hard-to-test-for bugs in it).

If you can state all operations you need to perform 100% in terms of the methods that CHM has, then do that, because CHM is vastly superior. It even has mechanisms for arbitrary operations: For example, unlike basic hashmaps, you can iterate through a CHM even if other threads are also messing with it, whereas with a normal hashmap you need to hold the lock for the *entire duration* of the operation, which means any other thread trying to do anything to that hashmap, even just 'ask for its size', need to wait. Hence, for most use cases, CHM results in orders of magnitude better performance.

Comment: thx, for your last point on iteration  HashMap from a thread while the get-check-if-null-then-set code is being performed by another (with synchronize(map)), in the case of a HashMap, even the first thread should acquire a lock on the map object, it means any thread performing anything on map should use synchronize on map ? that is right ? 
In the case of CHM there is no point in that particular case of using operations other than putIfAbsent or computeIfAbsent, any other operation would lead us to a check-null-then-set pattern and thus making it mandatory to use synchronize ? is it correct ?

Comment: If you don't have a CHM, this: " it means any thread performing anything on map should use synchronize on map ?" is correct. "n the case of CHM there is no point in that particular case of using operations other than putIfAbsent or computeIfAbsent" yes - non-atomic things aren't atomic, and you need to remember that. You can read the javadocs on CHM's `iterator()` method for more info on the behaviour of iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> in first approach the [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method only synchronizes on the bucket

That is incorrect, [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) doesn't synchronize on anything, it uses different mechanics to ensure thread safety.

> Would the second approach work fine with just a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) ?

Yes, except the second approach is flawed. If using synchronization to make a `Map` thread-safe, then all access of the `Map` should use synchronization. As such, it would be best to call [`Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-). Performance will be worse than using `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```java
private final Map<Integer, Object> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

> let's assume we don't want to use the `putIfAbsent` method.

Why? Oh, because it wastes a allocation if the key is already in the map, which is why we should be using [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead

```java
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Object());
```

Comment: Note that Collections.synchronizedMap is mostly useless here. You can't perform `if (!map.containsKey(k)) map.put(k, v);` in a safe fashion, even if `map` is the result of invoking `Collections.synchronizedMap` (only if you then also add a synchronized block), whereas e.g. CHM's `putIfAbsent(k, v)` does get the job "Add mapping k->v but only if there is no mapping for k yet" done - without needing a sync block. So, CHM not just outperforms, synchronizedMap mostly doesn't even do what you'd want.

Comment: Thx, I see, even with a synchronizedMap I should deal with the race condition by introducing the synchronized block, that means it don't prevent the race condition by itself here, and so the point of synchronizedMap is to have synchronized operations so that no race condition would occur inside  the execution of it's operations themselves (synchronized put, synchronized get, synchronized size and so one), is that right ?

Comment: in CHM a thread does hold the lock for a portion of the map right ?

Comment: @saadoune Correct on first comment. --- For second comment, see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): *"However, even though all operations are thread-safe, **retrieval operations do not entail locking**, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access."*